# Can't override default value for optional parameter in POST request on Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm starting with Symfony 4.3 and I'm struggling to find how to use optional parameters in a POST request.

In the documentation it says I should use `defaults` to specify the optional parameters of my request. However, Symfony seems to be ignoring my `POST` parameters and getting the default values all the time.

```
class NewController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route(
     *     "/app/new",
     *     name="app_new",
     *     methods={"POST"},
     *     defaults={"app_type":"teste", "name":"defaultVal", "phone":"", "url":""}
     *     )
     *
     * Creates new application authorization flow
     */
    public function indexAction($app_type, $name, $phone, $url)
    {
//        $appType = $this->getParameter('app_type');

        return new Response('Hello ' . $name . PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

When any parameter sent via POST is ignored:

```
$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/new -d "name=John&app_type=45533"
```

Returns

> Hello defaultVal

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the different parameter types.

"Route" parameters are not the same thing as "request" parameters.

What you are defining with the `@Route` annotation are, appropriately, route parameters. Basically, different path segments  you can use as parameters in your application.

Typically, something like this:

```
/blogpost/{id}
```

Where `id` can be injected as `$id` in your application controller.

In your case, you are defining default values for path segments you do not even define in your route definition... so there is no way to get any value for those besides the default values.

You can rewrite your controller action like this:

```php
/**
 * @Route(
 *     "/app/new",
 *     name="app_new",
 *     methods={"POST"})
 */
public function indexAction(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request)
{
    $appType = $request->get('app_type', 'yourDefaultValue');
    $name    = $request->get('name', 'anotherDefaultValue');
    $phone   = $request->get('phone');
    $url     = $request->get('url');

    return new Response('Hello ' . $name . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Comment: You are right @yivi. 4.6 is my Symfony CLI version. I'm using 4.3. I'll update the question. I tried a lot of stuff following the docs, but didn't see your approach anywhere since then. Thank you very much for the solution and help.